# Elmah code-first SQL Server logging

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first, elmah

I installed Elmah via nuget. It usually works will if I use an `.edmx`. However I am using a code-first `DbContext`. Elmah seems to be sending the emails but it doesn't log to the database.

Any idea what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will work just fine with code first. You do not need the ELMAH_ERROR table as a part of your context. As long as you ran the elmah SQL in your database and setup your config correctly it WILL log to the database. Please share your config code, it should look something like this (a small portion of the config):

```
<elmah>
    <errorLog type="Elmah.SqlErrorLog, Elmah" connectionStringName="elmah-sqlserver" applicationName="YOUR_APPLICATION" />
    <security allowRemoteAccess="yes" />
</elmah>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="elmah-sqlserver" connectionString="Data Source=YOUR_SERVER;User ID=YOUR_USER_ID;Password=YOUR_PASSWORD;Initial Catalog=YOUR_CATALOG;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: what about the stored procedures it uses to write to the database?

Comment: Yes you need to run the entire elmah script in your database, including stored procedures.